# What is the best best way to make one Pressable's text color change out of three <Pressable/>s

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am all new to React Native, and trying to understand how to make one `pressable JSX element` active (Active means the text colour change/Icon colour change) when the user clicks it (Any of the three Pressables)

Example:
Consider I have three pressables as below

```
<Pressable>
    <Text><Icon name="flame" size={13} color={GRAY} /> 123</Text>
</Pressable>
<Pressable>
    <Text><Icon name="flame" size={13} color={GRAY} /> 456</Text>
</Pressable>
<Pressable>
    <Text><Icon name="flame" size={13} color={GRAY} /> 789</Text>
</Pressable>
```

Now I am looking for a solution that can change the user clicked pressable's ICON colour change to RED, using the best possible way.

Note: I am going to render something based on these button clicks, so looking for a best possible dynamic solution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example for one button:

```
// Here we keep track of button state. Initial value is false.
const [isButtonActive, setButtonActive] = useState(false)

// On button press, set state to be the opposite of current value.
const onPressButton = () => setButtonActive((isButtonActive) => !isButtonActive)

return (
    <Pressable onPress={onPressButton}>
        <Text><Icon name="flame" size={13} color={isButtonActive ? 'red' : 'gray'} />123</Text>
    </Pressable>
)
```

Similarly, you can define state for all of the buttons and use the values to conditionally render components.

Comment: Thank you, this answer solves my problem partially, but if one button is active, I want to make other buttons inactive. could you please help?

Comment: I created an Expo snack for you: https://snack.expo.dev/3G-3BlGmU